# I want to make Responsive appbar in flutter. According to the design that I have

Tags: flutter, dart

**This is the design of appbar that I want to create using flutter and that should be responsive for all types of mobile devices and Tablets. Please let me know what to do to achieve this.**

[image]

```
Widget _buildHeader() {
return Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* .22,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
  color: Color(0xFF0A182E),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 40),
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("homebtn clicked..!!"); //Home button
              },
              child: Text(
                "Home",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *.47,),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print("profilebtn clicked");
            },
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.07,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.14,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/profilebtn.png"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .04,),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("Roomsbtn clicked.!");
              },
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  "ROOMS",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print("Devicesbtn clicked.!");
            },
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                "DEVICES",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *.27,),
          Transform.scale(          //add Button
            scale: .65,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("Redplusbtn clicked.!");
                _onButtonPressed();
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 45,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

**This is what I have tried but I find this approach is lengthy and not responsive.I have tried in other devices and appbar is not responsive so I want to make this appbar in a Standard way.**

Comment: please add a code what you have tried so far and what did not work and you need a help with

Comment: @LonelyWolf please see the code that I have tried but I think this is not a standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is way better solution. First of all there is no need to call media query to find a width and height. Another thing is that you can use AppBar widget and rework it to the way you like. Look at this example and amend it to your needs..

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[Text('Hello'), Icon(Icons.email)],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Option1'),
                      Text('Option2'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.language)
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Container())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting the higher elements (title and picture) on the AppBar and the lower elements (Room, devices and plus icon) on a TabBar.

AppBar: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html
TabBar: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html

Answer (score -1):

You can identify the customer device first using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/device_info

the next steps, you can set the condition of the appbar in each device.
for more details you can check this link https://iiro.dev/2018/01/28/implementing-adaptive-master-detail-layouts/